# shell script variable in the middle of command

Tags: shell, variables, command

```
#!/bin/bash
STR=000 
while : 
do
    echo -e '\uE${STR}'
    sleep 1
done
```

On a shell script, how can I merge a variable in a command? I would like the above to be the same as:

```
echo -e '\uE000'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes `"`:

```
echo -e "\uE${STR}"
```

Single quotes `'` prevent parameter expansion.